# FreeBSD install supervisor

Tags: freebsd, supervisord

I like to install supervisor on FreeBSD. When I try to install from "/usr/ports/sysutils/py-supervisor" with "make install clean"

I get the error:
`make: "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk" line 1175: Unable to determine OS version.  Either define OSVERSION, install /usr/include/sys/param.h or define SRC_BASE.`

I cant find a fix on the internet. How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

For me on another port the Problem was an empty src dir.
Get the FreeBSD version via `uname -a`, look up your branch here https://cgit.freebsd.org/src and get the sources via.

```
git clone -b stable/12 --depth 1 https://git.freebsd.org/src.git /usr/src
```

Note: 12.2 is the latest of "stable/12" as of writing this 24.11.2021. The -b stands for branch.